# Unable to capture Windows Image

Tags: windows-10, dism, windows-pe

I'm unable to capture image of Windows 10 with dism.
When I try the dism throws me error 2:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

I use this command to capture image:

```
DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:D:\install.wim /Capture-Dir:C:\ /Name:"Recovery" /Description:"My custom recovery"
```

Drive letters: C - System partition, D - partition on other disk where file should be saved.

The same command works without problems when capturing Win 7 Pro image.

Can someone help?

Update: I pasted log from DISM maybe this helps:
https://pastebin.com/e4rB6HaX

Comment: Try to put `ImageFile` inside a subfolder, not on the root.

Comment: I would follow exactly what the Error Message is stating. Maybe it cannot create the `D:\install.wim` Binary File. Check the State of the `D:` Software (Primary?) Partition. Try to create a File on it. Check the Privileges that are already set on the `D:\ ` Folder. And do not expect much from the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System.

Comment: I tried to capture image either on root and in subfolder of D:\ drive. 
I tried also to capture image to other media as external hdd drive but to no avail

Comment: I duplicated your command on Windows 10 with `/CaptureDir` and it works fine. Try running it while booting in Safe mode.

Comment: I executed command either while system is offline via console (Shift+F10) from installation media (USB stick) and from Windows 10 troubleshoot (restart while holding Shift key). In both scenarios the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I finally found what was causing it : I was using a USB key as a destination disk but it had not enough memory on it. Captured image can be very large : generally 5Go to 10Go